# Swift/iOS8: set imageView for next View Controller before Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

depending on a few parameters I am trying to set an Image on the second VC, but somehow it always returns null??

this is what i do:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showDetail"  {
            println("going forth!")
            println(self.myButton.selected)

            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailVC

            if myButton.selected == true {
                var newImage = UIImage(named:"Test1")
                var oldImage = controller?.imageView.image
                println(oldImage)

                oldImage = newImage
            } else {
                var newImage = UIImage(named:"Test2")
                var oldImage = controller?.imageView.image
                println(oldImage)

                oldImage = newImage
            }

        } else {
            println("roflcopter")
        }
    }
```

the detail VC basically has "nothing":

```
import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var testString:String!

    @IBAction func goBacktoMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        println("going back")

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("view Did Load")
        println(testString)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

the second VC has a default image set via Storyboard but when I stop with a breakpoint @let controller it will tell me that imageview actually is null, does this only get set once the detail vc was shown once?

€dit: setting the string and printing it out on the second VC works perfectly fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where are you setting the image?
Inside the `prepareForSegue` the `UIImageView IBOutlet` will not have loaded. You have to declare an image variable in your `DetailVC` class like below and set that image in `viewDidLoad`.

```
class  DetailVC
{
    var image:UIImage? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

In your `prepareSegue` function, set

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailVC
controller?.image = //Your Image according to conditions.
```

Comment: Correct, in the `prepareForSegue` method, the view hasn't been loaded yet. So you assign the image view which is overwritten by the `IBOutlet` connection later when the view is loaded.

Comment: the image has a default set in the storyboard, with your help I could now set the image and alternatively i can also just hand over the named string to set it later in viewDidLoad with UIImage(named:)

is there any difference in memory handling? i guess not as the image is only loaded when the view is shown?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a UIImage variable in the destination segue, pass the image object to it.

On viewDidLoad on the destination object, assign the image to the imageView.Image property

Most probably the Outlet is not yet initialized